# Why does my Code work on Internet explorer version 8 on localhost not on server, but not on internet explorer version 10

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a code which work on internet explorer version 8 on localhost.It does not work on server(Filezilla).Same code does not work on internet explorer version 10 on localhost also on server(filezilla).I want solution so that it can run on IE version 10 on localhost as well as on server.Code is as follow.

```
<?php
    function get_user_browser() {
        $u_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
        $ub = '';
        if (preg_match('/MSIE/i', $u_agent)) {
            $ub = "ie";
        } elseif (preg_match('/Firefox/i', $u_agent)) {
            $ub = "firefox";
        } elseif (preg_match('/Safari/i', $u_agent)) {
            $ub = "safari";
        } elseif (preg_match('/Chrome/i', $u_agent)) {
            $ub = "chrome";
        } elseif (preg_match('/Flock/i', $u_agent)) {
            $ub = "flock";
        } elseif (preg_match('/Opera/i', $u_agent)) {
            $ub = "opera";
        }

        return $ub;
    }

    //echo get_user_browser();
    $browser = get_user_browser();
    if ($browser == 'ie') {
        echo "<script>alert('Your Browser is not compatible, Please Update the version')</script>";
        echo "<script>window.open('www.google.com','_self')</script>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: It Working Fine In My Browser

Comment: Couldn't you just do this on the frontend with https://modernizr.com/ ?

Comment: Like @Chris suggested, please do this front end. Even better, you can do it with css only. Detecting IE is a trivial thing.. no need to do it back-end.

Answer (score 1):

Detecting IE nowadays is a very trivial thing that doesn't require such a shred hammer. Of course, you can check it in the back end like that. But, let me explain why it is not the best approach.

Everytime that a client requests a page, it requires YOUR time to process its browser name through a regex, while he could easily check for it himself. He is the one who is running the browser on his machine.

I would recommend that you ask the user to check himself if the page is optimized for his browser. Now, why is it viable? If the users trick you into believing they are using a browser they are not, the only victims is them. In that way, you can save free processing time. Aren't the free things awesome?

The problem can be resolved by using only HTML, CSS and a box:

**CSS**

```
#incompatibleBrowser { display:none; }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="incompatibleBrowser">Get a better browser! [link]</div>
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Here, *ie.css* would contain:

**CSS**

```
#incompatibleBrowser { display:block; }
// other rules that you might find appropriate for IE users
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in function get_browser()

Link: http://php.net/manual/de/function.get-browser.php

(Beware to have the actual browsercap.ini in your directory - you'll find it in the link above).

But first of all you should check what strings are delivered by your browser/s, since lots of plug-ins allow your browser to imitate (fake) beeing another browser.
This will help you analyse the problem quickly.

And as you can see here:
http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Browserlist/, *MSIE* as check-parameter is not the best way, at least not if you put it first in your check-routine.